# How to perform web deploy in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, webdeploy, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-web-deploy

When I click publish ASP.NET 5 project in visual studio, only 3 target I can choose:
Microsoft Azure Web Apps,
Import,
File System

There're no Web Deploy or Web Deploy package as shown in ASP.NET 4.6 Project.
How can I perform Web Deploy on ASP.NET 5 project?

Comment: IIRC, web deploy support is not there yet.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787379/non-azure-deployment-through-vs-2015-rc/29791193#29791193

Comment: I suggest you look at using dnu to create deployments though webdeploy is unlikely to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing an ASP.NET 5 project to an IIS server with Web Deploy requires a few additional steps in comparison to an ASP.NET 4 project.

Before asp.net dev team provide a better solution, you can just follow the instruction from docs.asp.net [Publishing to IIS with Web Deploy using Visual Studio 2015](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy.html)

To publish an ASP.NET 5 application to a remote IIS server the following steps are required.

1. Configure your remote IIS server to support ASP.NET 5
2. Create a publish profile
3. Customize the profile to support Web Deploy publish