# Deploying ASP.Net Web API to Remote IIS with VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

In vs 2013 publish options, you are able to plug in a remote IIS server and publish to it.

In VS2015 there is no such option.  I followed the walk-through here
[Non-Azure Deployment through VS 2015 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787379/non-azure-deployment-through-vs-2015-rc)

this allows me to put in server information, but it still fails to publish with ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.  I have a VS 2013 installation using the exact same publish settings with no issue.

I find it hard to believe that this feature has been removed from VS 2015.  Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

I am fixing exactly the same now :-)

- Check that you have **Microsoft Web Deploy** (v3 or the version you are using) installed with ALL components in destination server.
- Check registry **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server** for RemoteRestrictions key. It should be empty
- Check IIS settings. In the host look for **Management Service**. Check that **enable remote connections** is **enabled**.
- Check that **WMSVC** service is started (Web Management Service)
- Check also **msdepsvc** service.
- Check that your user has **permissions** (make it administrator). Probably this is not the problem as it would give you "Access Denied error"

Comment: Thanks, but none of this helped :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your website using Web Deploy and make sure these followings are in place.

1. The site names must be exactly matched in both Visual studio and on IIS server
2. Make sure the sever installed with the same.net framework as your visual studio (e.g ASP, ASP.net 4.5…)
3. Make sure port 8172 is open on the server(8172 is used for web deploy)

Check this link fore more detail on how to deploy your website using Web Deploy
https://martinbuberl.com/blog/deploy-aspnet-mvc-on-amazon-ec2-with-web-deploy/